# Windows - Dark theme messed up

Tags: windows-explorer, window, bug, dark-mode

After enabling dark mode on Windows the file explorer still has some stuff showing white. And now the text is also white so I can't see anything. Same thing happens in the context menu that drops down if I click on the window title bar. (The context menu inside the window is ok). Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you do a Reboot?

Comment: yes of course. And disabled/re-enabled dark mode multiple times. Same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here. What you see as White should be darker Grey so white text is easily seen and read.

1. Make sure Windows 10 is fully up to date.
2. Update the BIOS, Chipset if you have it, and Video drivers are all updated.
3. Return to Light mode, and run the initial Windows 10 Repairs.

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
>
> SFC  /SCANNOW

Now re-enable Dark Mode and test.

4. Make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). log into the new account and test Dark Mode in the new User Account. If this works the main user Profile is damaged and needs to be replaced.
5. If all the above fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install:

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.
>
> Except for the last Repair Option (Keep Nothing), Repair cannot fix a
> damaged User Profile.

Good luck.